Git merge is reverted from master Branch Again I want to merge feature reverted branch into master branch
I created a branch and made some changes in there. I merged the master into my branch, but this was too early, so I reverted this merge-commit. After that, I made some new changes and commited multiple times.
...--o--o--*  -- o--o--o-----o   <-- master
            \     \           \
             o--o--o--x--o--o--o--o  <-- mybranch
                      |           |
             reverted merge       not merge all files

So if I want to merge now, it ignores files which were removed with the revert.
How can I merge all the files, without ignoring some files?
I need to merge the new changes and old changes including reverted files

Did you try to Rebase your branch ?

can't make sense of your graph.  did you use git revert to do the revert? and now you want to 'undo' the revert? if so you git revert the revert commit and that will put master  merge back in place properly.

As a sidenote, you revert commits only when you can't change history, i.e. on remote shared branches. A bad local merge is much easier to handle with git reset.

You cannot re-merge a reverted merge, because the revert undoes the effects of the merge but the merge itself is still there in the topology. The easiest solution in your situation might be simply to revert the revert. — By the way, you need to stop think about "changes" and "files". Git traffics in commits. A commit is a snapshot of your entire project.

I would agree with @RomainValeri 's statement if no other commits had been made.  With additional commits made, git rebase seems like a much clearer path then git reset does. git reset is workable but quite complicated in this case.

If this branch has been pushed elsewhere generally speaking what you want to do here is to do another git revert to revert the commit created by your prior git revert.  at that point with your merge from master into your branch, the difference between your branch and master should just be your changes you intended and any conflict resolution you did with master.
If it is a local and unpushed branch you can go another route, but, you may want to do that first ANYWAYS and then save it as a backup. git checkout -b mybranch_backup then go back to mybranch and perform an interactive rebase as @vatbub demonstrated to drop the merges you don't want and to drop the revert commit. In fact you could drop all of the merges and then merge in at the spot you wanted to.
Finally before pushing (or force pushing) you could do a git diff mybranch mybranch_backup to make sure that nothing changed except history if you are concerned about botching the contents during your rebasing.


We don't know whether OP has pushed OP's branch yet or not with the merge in it.  2. OP can always rebase afterwards.   Everything is still possible after reverting the revert and you have a clean patch difference as well to compare your changes to if you are concerned that you might 'botch' the corrections along the way.  That said I will update answer to include both paths.


Good edit. (I'm deleting my first comment which is no longer relevant.) I'd bet OP can definitely rewrite their branch at this point. If it were me, I'd either hard reset to before the first merge, then cherry-pick the range of commits after the revert, or do it in one shot with an interactive rebase which will automatically drop the merges, and you can just drop the revert commit. (Which is basically what you said in the edit.)

As @Romain Valeri has already said in the comments, a better approach to undo an undesired merge would be with a git reset.
... -- A  -- B -- C --- D ---- E ---- F     master
        \          \                   \
          G -- H -- I -- I' -- L - M -- N   mybranch

In fact, once you've merged master into mybranch at commit C, Git considers every change reachable from C and unreachable from G as merged into mybranch (G..C). Even if you perform a git revert right after the merge to revert its changes, from Git's perspective all those commits are still integrated into mybranch, it doesn't matter if the changes after it undo what the merge introduced. At commit I', C and B are still reachable even though I' undoes their modifications.
If you want to make those changes available again at your next merge, you need to reset mybranch at the commit before the undesired merge. The reset must be a mixed one, git reset --mixed H, where the index is set to commit H, while the working directory keeps all the changes you've made in the meantime (this includes also the changes from the first unwanted merge). At this point, you can break your changes into several commits (L, M, and more if you need) and finally merge master into mybranch. Also, if some of the commits you've made after the first undesired merge contained changes on the same file(s), you can break the hunk of changes with git add --patch.
This solution will create a few merge conflicts, since mybranch already contains some of the changes coming from master, but it's a good approach if you want to actually re-merge master into mybranch. Also, the more commits you introduce after the undesired merge, the messier it gets to restore them.

Important
For safety, before proceeding with the reset of mybranch, make a copy of it (mybranch_backup). Like so, if something goes wrong during the reset and re-commit of its changes, you can always bring back mybranch to its current state with a git reset --hard mybranch_backup. You could also achieve the same result by inspecting git reflog, but I think it's easier when the commit you need is pointed by a nice and well-named ref.

An interactive rebase may help you to fix the problem:

Run git rebase --interactive master. This will attempt to rebase your branch on the latest commit in master. Alternatively, you may want to try git rebase --interactive <commit-hash-of-the-commit-you-branched-off-initially> which will rebase on the commit that you branched off initially from.
A text editor will open. The text editor will contain a line for each commit that will look something like this:

pick deadbee First commit on mybranch
pick a13465a Merge master into mybranch
pick f6e3c9a Revert 'Merge master into mybranch'
pick fa1afe1 Next commit on mybranch
pick e4a126f Merge master into mybranch


Change the lines for all the commits that you want to delete by replacing the pick with drop. The text file should look like this now:

pick deadbee First commit on mybranch
drop a13465a Merge master into mybranch
drop f6e3c9a Revert 'Merge master into mybranch'
pick fa1afe1 Next commit on mybranch
drop e4a126f Merge master into mybranch


Save the text file and close the text editor. Git will now attempt to rewrite your branch while deleting those merge commits. In case it fails (e.g. because of merge conflicts), it will interrupt the rebase giving you an opportunity to fix the merge conflicts. If at that point you want to abort and start the rebase from scratch, you can run git rebase --abort and git will revert everything to the state it was in before you started the rebase.

Here's a link to the interactive rebase docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode

Will the merge commits show up in the rebase?

Ah, true, I didn't think about that. I guess we'll see if it works for OP.

merge commits won't show up unless you use the preserve merge flag, otherwise youre just going to get the individual commits.  not sure how its going to handle the revert in a rebase situation like this to be honest.  which is why I didnt advise it

In that case, an alternative idea could be to just to create a new branch mybranch2 (or create a backup and reset it to its base) and cherry-pick all individual commits.
